# If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot, can you cast that spell using a spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-slots

A 10th level Drow warlock (for instance) has the following Drow Magic racial trait (PHB p. 24), in addition to its warlock spellcasting abilities:

> You know the *dancing lights* cantrip. When you reach 3rd level, you can cast the *faerie fire* spell once per day. When you reach 5th level, you can also cast the *darkness* spell once per day. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

**Can the Drow warlock cast *faerie fire* (which is not on the warlock spell list) using a warlock spell slot?**

**Can it cast *darkness* (which is on the warlock spell list) using a warlock spell slot?**

---

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/SA_Compendium_1.01.pdf#page=3) says this about the Magic Initiate feat:

> **If you’re a spellcaster, can you pick your own class when you gain the Magic Initiate feat?** Yes, the feat doesn’t say you can’t. For example, if you’re a wizard and gain the Magic Initiate feat, you can choose wizard and thereby learn two more wizard cantrips and another 1st-level wizard spell.
>
> **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?** Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes. For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. Similarly, if you are a wizard and pick that class for the feat, you learn a 1st-level wizard spell, which you could add to your spellbook and subsequently prepare.

But this specifically requires you to pick the feat for one of your classes to be able to cast the spell learnt using your class spell slots, and does not seem directly applicable.

A Warlock can use warlock Pact Magic spell slots to cast spells learnt from levels of another spellcasting class, per the multiclass spellcasting rules (PHB p. 164):

> If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

Similarly, if the warlock has learnt the invocation Mask of Many Faces (PHB p. 112)...

> You can cast *disguise self* at will, without expending a spell slot.

...**Can the warlock cast *disguise self* using a spell slot, e.g. to decrease the chance it can be dispelled?**

Answer (score 36):

## No, you can't cast it using a spell slot.

Spells you can cast because of your race aren't spells you know, and thus can't be spells you prepare. Per the PHB (p. 201, ["Known and Prepared Spells"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#KnownandPreparedSpells)):

> Before a spellcaster can use a spell, he or she must have the spell firmly fixed in mind ...

... and it goes on to describe some of the class-specific variations of knowing and preparing spells. But in any case, having a feature from your race or class that allows you to cast a spell isn't the same as knowing the spell.

This is spelled out clearly in the [multiclassing rules for Pact Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) quoted in the question (PHB p. 164; emphasis mine).

> If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you **know or have prepared** from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

Likewise, the [Drow Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/elf#DarkElfDrow) trait clearly distinguishes the **known** cantrip from the merely **castable** other spells (PHB, p. 24; bold for emphasis mine):

> You **know** the *dancing lights* cantrip. When you reach 3rd level, you **can cast** the *faerie fire* spell once per day. When you reach 5th level, you **can also cast** the *darkness* spell once per day. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

If the intent of the rules was that Drow also *knew* the non-cantrip spells, it would say so.

Comment: It is the mechanic equivalent of the *spell-like abilities* of previous editions. They just ditched *sp* and *su* as ability classifiers. Even so, nobody uses a spell slot for cantrips. +1

Comment: @Marq What about the racial descriptions that say "you learn" rather then "you know" or "you can cast"?

Comment: @Protonflux Can you give me an example?

Comment: It may be worth updating the answer given the [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), which updated each class's Spellcasting (or Pact Magic) feature to say you can only use that class's slots to cast spells of that class (e.g. "cleric spells" for cleric), in accordance with what the Sage Advice Compendium says about Magic Initiate.

Comment: @V2Blast That is definitely not how spell slots work under the Multiclassing rules. Can you clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: @MarkWells: [I explained what that change did in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54400105#54400105)  I think it has no impact on multiclassing directly, because the multiclass spellcasting rules override specific Spellcasting features in terms of determining the number of spell slots you have (if you have the Spellcasting feature from more than one class) and in determining whether you can use Pact Magic slots to cast spells known/prepared from the Spellcasting feature or vice versa.

Comment: @MarkWells: If single-classed, at least, it basically prevents using slots from your Spellcasting or Pact Magic feature to cast things that aren't spells of that class for you. That is, the Sage Advice Compendium already said you can't use your wizard slots to cast the 1st-level spell from the Magic Initiate feature unless you are a wizard; the errata made it so that claim is actually true by RAW.  The same is true for other feats that say you "know"/"learn" a leveled spell - for single-classed casters, at least. I'm less sure how it interacts with multiclassing.

Answer (score 3):

### You can only use spell slots on a spell gained from a feature if it is a class spell for you *and* the spell is either known/learned or prepared

#### (Besides magic items) A spell must be known/learned or prepared in order to use spell slots to cast it

The "[Known and Prepared Spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#KnownandPreparedSpells)" section states:

> Before a spellcaster can use a spell, he or she must have the spell firmly fixed in mind, or must have access to the spell in a magic item. [...]
>
> [...] In every case, the number of spells a caster can have fixed in mind at any given time depends on the character's level.

These quotes establish that casting a spell requires it to be known/learned or prepared and not merely be cast-able without the use of spell slots.

For this reason, features such as Drow Magic's *darkness* or *faerie fire* cannot be cast using spell slots; these spells are not known/learned or prepared despite being cast-able:

> You know the dancing lights cantrip. When you reach 3rd level, **you can cast** the faerie fire spell once per day. When you reach 5th level, **you can also cast** the darkness spell once per day. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for these spells.

Note that this also means that if a feature makes a spell learned/known but you class *prepares* spells then you *still* cannot cast it because a class which prepares spells can only cast spells that they have prepared, not merely known/learned.

#### Even if a spell from a feature *is* known/learned or prepared, spell slots can only be used to cast spells that are associated with (one of) your class(es)

The *Players Handbook* has received [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) changing the wordings of every Spellcasting and Pact Magic feature (the example below is for Sorcerers with the pre-errata quote followed by the post-errata one):

> The sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your spells of 1st level and higher.
>
> The sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your **sorcerer** spells of 1st level and higher.

Thus, the spell slots provided by a class can only be used to cast spells from/of that class. They cannot be used to cast spells that are not considered their own class spells.

---

#### How do you know if a spell is associated with (one of) you class(es)?

The following three Q/A's (one is closed as a duplicate) have differing answers:

- [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182)
- [Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954)
- [If I am a Celestial Warlock and I take the Magic Initiate - Cleric (Cure Wounds), does that now count as a Warlock spell for me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157765)

It seems inconclusive then, and that a GM could have to rule whether or not *misty step* (which appears on the sorcerer spell list) counts as a sorcerer spell when it is obtained through something like the the Fey Teleportation feat [discussed elsewhere](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110944):

> You **learn** the *misty step* spell and can cast it once without expending a spell slot. You regain the ability to cast it in this way when you finish a short or long rest.

Thus *misty step* is considered a learned/known spell but whether or not it is also considered a sorcerer spell will come down to a GM decision.

---

#### Wizard *might* be an exception to all this

The Sage Advice Compendium states:

> Q. **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?**
>
> A. Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes. For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. **Similarly, if you are a wizard and pick that class for the feat, you learn a 1st-level wizard spell, which you could add to your spellbook and subsequently prepare.**
>
> In short, you must follow your character’s normal spellcasting rules, which determine whether you can expend spell slots on the 1st-level spell you learn from Magic Initiate.

There's a lot in there, but the bolded section is what I'd like to point out. *Somehow* if a Wizard knows a spell they *might* be able to add it into their spellbook and thus prepare that spell. The SAC doesn't exactly explain *why* a Wizard can do this, but it seems that they could. Perhaps they turn it into a spell scroll first or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

### Not if you stick to RAW, but the clear trend is against current RAW.

The other answers have done an amazing job of explaining RAW, so I won't rehash that, but it is telling that ALL of the new "you can cast x spell" feats and abilities have been tagged "you can also cast with any spell slots you have". The newer abilities are almost all stronger than the old ones too!

Yes they could have been clearer and released an errata, but there are so many dodgy rules they haven't clarified yet that if we assume no errata = intended then we will be playing some very odd games. Plus they have a job to do, which is to make money, and faffing on with errata like this probably would never get high up the priority list.

The new addendum to the similar abilities is 100% in my view and admission that there is not only nothing wrong with allowing them to be cast with slots, but that it was intended all along and they are just finally correcting it.

Also I am not a fan of sticking to RAW just because, and where is the logic in being able to cast a spell and not being able to cast the spell at the same time? Just let it happen.

Comment: If I could find a logic in being able to cast but not cast, it would be for racial traits. The process of casting a spell because you've learned it and casting a spell because your physical body can naturally do it are most likely different processes. Think about skills like being able to stand on your two feet, something that's quite natural for us human but takes practice and learning for most animals. The result is the same, but the method and how natural it is aren't quite the same, which can bring different limits. Then again, magic is magic, so it's hard to apply logic to it at all.

Comment: +1 I really hope that someone involved in the One D&D effort takes the time to read sites like this to get input on rules that need cleaned up wordings and errata. This would make the game more robust and enjoyable to run, in a way just adding more powers and new options will not. The questionnaire they made for it had no focus on fixing such issues however, so my expectations do not match those hopes...

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Yup that questionnaire was terrible. It had no focus on anything other than popularity, at least the one I did. Popularity is important, but if they never understand the why then they can't replicate it properly.

Answer (score 1):

### Only if the feature explicitly says so

As explained in other answers, the case for the original Drow Magic trait is that no, you cannot cast those spells using spell slots, because you don’t “know” them in the context of your class. It’s not a wizard/sorcerer/cleric etc spell, so you can’t cast it with the Spellcasting (or Pact Magic) feature you get from your class.

A helpful way to think about this is that *mechanically* you are casting a spell, but *narratively* you are using an innate magical ability common to your species. This is often called out by making exceptions to the normal rules, for example Githzerai use of *mage hand*. From the updated version of the race in *Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse*:

> **Githzerai Psionics**
>
> You know the *mage hand* cantrip, and the hand is invisible when you cast the cantrip with this trait.

Making it invisible allows existing mechanics to model minor telekinesis.

Since the question was asked, however, other races, updates to existing ones and even feats have granted the ability to cast a spell without a slot once per day, and explicitly allowed the spell to be used with spell slots as well. To use the updated Githzerai as an example again, the Githzerai Psionics trait continues (emphasis mine):

> Starting at 3rd level, you can cast the *shield* spell with this trait. Starting at 5th level, you can also cast the *detect thoughts* spell with it. Once you cast *shield* or *detect thoughts* with this trait, you can’t cast that spell with it again until you finish a long rest. **You can also cast either of those spells using any spell slots you have of the appropriate level.**

Note that the extra utility of using the spells with spell slots is balanced by the fact that you only get one free cast of *either* spell per day, not one free casting of each one.

Most of the races with innate spells from sources published after the *Players Handbook* have had their traits similarly updated to allow them to use them with spell slots, with the same limitation. The ”Character Origins” playtest document for *One D&D* indicates it’s likely that will also be the case for races from the *Players Handbook* in the 2024 version as well.

But if you’re playing with the original PHB version of the Drow (or Tiefling), you are out of luck - though you have a model and a good case for asking your DM to make a ruling allowing use of your Drow Magic spells with your spell slots.

Comment: I keep seeing this kind of logic, do you really not think the new printing is an admission that the old printing is wrong?

Comment: I think this is technically correct, and a good summary of the current situation. Yes, WotC seems extremely likely to do away with the limitation, but in as far as they have not *published* errata/updates for the PHB races, these still are the rules, and it will only change if they eventually do publish an update (which I expect to happen, most likely as part of One D&D).

Comment: @SeriousBri I think it’s an indication they’ve changed their minds about the design, but this is meant to be a bridging question. The new wording suggests this interpretation of the original racial trait spells is correct; this isn’t a clarification, or a fix for an error, but a design change. The new wording doesn’t invalidate the old, and hasn’t been issued as errata to clarify intent.

Answer (score -6):

### Yes, you can cast it using a spell slot.

Spells you can cast because of your race are spells you know, and thus can be spells you prepare.

This works essentially the same way as if you had gained access to this spell through multi-classing.

Comment: Welcome to the rpg stack! Please keep in mind we require answers to be backed up properly and I feel this answer could benefit from more references. You can see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8697/33707) for details on this. Thank you for contributing and happy gaming!