# If you get a spell through a racial ability, can you also take it as a spell from a class?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits

Say, for example, I'm a drow or a tiefling. I have the *darkness* spell once a day. However, I'm a warlock with Devil's Sight and I want as many chances to cast *darkness* as possible. Can I take *darkness* as a warlock spell as well, or can I only take it once as a racial spell?

Because I can't use slots to cast the racial spell ([If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102875/if-you-have-the-ability-to-cast-a-spell-without-a-spell-slot-can-you-cast-that-s)), I can't do that for extra uses. So could I, in that example, take *darkness* again or am I stuck with only the racial ability?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, as indicated in the question you linked, spellcasting via different means are basically treated separately for rules purposes, except where otherwise noted. So a drow warlock 3 can cast *darkness* once per day as a racial ability, and separately, can cast *darkness* up to twice between short rests using their Pact Magic slots, if it's one of their spells known.

Comment: Although this is a good answer, it would be better with rules references or quotes.

Comment: @keithcurtis I don't disagree, but I couldn't think of any exact citations; it's more the *absence* of any rules that would prevent OP from doing what they're trying to do. Open to suggestions.

Comment: One note that may be worth mentioning, the ability score that affects the spell is dependent on the source of the spell.  So if you are a teifling wizard, and you get the darkness spell from both sources, casting as the racial ability uses your charisma, but casting as a wizard uses your intelligence. (not that it effects darkness, but it could on other spells)

Answer (score 3):

**Your race and class abilities are independent of one another**

Take the darkness spell.