# Can I use spell slots to cast the spell granted from the Fey Teleportation feat additional times?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, spellcasting, spell-slots

I have a high-elf wizard with the Fey Teleportation feat. According to the feat "You learn the Misty Step spell, and can cast it once without expending a spell slot. You regain the ability to cast it in this way when you finish a short or long rest."

Does this mean I can cast Misty Step additional times using spell slots? As a wizard, do I need to have the spell prepared in order to cast it using a spell slot?

Comment: I think your question would be improved by adding a subquestion regarding whether the answer changes if your character is a Sorcerer.

Comment: [Related] [If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875) (and despite the title, not a duplicate.)

Comment: @Pyrotechnical it can be generalized for any other class. The real question to broaden it beyond wizard is "even if it is not on my class/level spell list?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Yes, you can

The [Fey Teleportation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/fey-teleportation) feat (XGtE, p. 74) says:

> You learn the *misty step* spell and can cast it once without expending a spell slot. You regain the ability to cast it **in this way** when you finish a short or long rest.

Since it says you **learn** the *misty step* spell, I would argue that you can then use it with other spell slots as well.

This is reinforced by the fact that it says "You regain the ability to cast it **in this way**...". If it was only intended to be a once per long or short rest ability it should have said "You regain the ability to cast it...".

Further evidence can be found by looking at the [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/magic-initiate) feat (PHB, p. 168):

> Choose a class: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You
> learn two cantrips of your choice from that class's spell list.
>
> In addition, choose one 1st-level spell from that same list. You learn
> that spell and can cast it at its lowest level. Once you cast it, you
> must finish a long rest before you can cast it again using this feat.

And this question about it from the [Sage Advice Compendium v2.2 (p. 8)](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=8):

> **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?**
>
> Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your
> classes. [...] In short, you must follow your character’s normal
> spellcasting rules, which determine whether you can expend spell slots
> on the 1st-level spell you learn from Magic Initiate.

This confirms that you can use spell slots to cast spells that you learn from feats, which is what happens in Fey Teleportation.

However this does also bring up the restriction that the spell, in this case Misty Step, would have to be on your class spell list in order to use it by using spell slots.

Additionally, prepared spellcasters would have to have Misty Step prepared in order to use it using slots.

Any other restriction or conditions of casting for your class also apply as normal.

[This answer from the Sage Advice Compendium v2.2 (p. 3)](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3) suggests that maybe prepared casters would not be able to use these known spells as prepared ones:

> **If a druid takes the Magic Initiate feat and chooses detect magic as their one spell, can the druid cast that spell as a ritual?**
>
> A druid’s Ritual Casting requires a ritual to be prepared. The spell
> from Magic Initiate is known but not prepared.

---

Rules designer Jeremy Crawford has confirmed that these feats work using the same ruling as MI in [this unofficial tweet from December 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/937860581180162049).

Twitter user Isaac Leong asked:

> How do the elven racial magic feats (Drow High Magic, Fey Teleportation and Wood Elf Magic) in Xanathar's interact with spell slots? They say that you know the spells and can cast them without expending spell slots, so can you use spell slots with them?

Another Twitter user, Armando Doval, replied:

> You have to follow your class's Spellcasting (or Pact Magic) rules to cast a spell using spell slots (e.g. A wizard has to prepare the spell from their spellbook.) See "Magic Initiate" in Sage Advice Compendium https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/rules-answers-october-2017
> [...]
> I understand the wording is different. The part that's relevant is that you have to follow your class's spellcasting rules. Wood Elf Magic, etc don't say you learn the spell or that it counts as a  spell for you.
> If they didn't add "in this way" to those feats it'd sound like you can't cast them at all after using the feat. They're distinguishing the 1 use you get from the feat from other ways you might have to cast the spell.

Crawford confirmed this interpretation in a reply:

> Your interpretation is 100 percent correct, @armando_doval.

Comment: Huh.  I was gonna answer the other way, but I think you might be right.  It does say you learn the spell.  That means you should be able to cast it using spell slots, provided those spell slots belong to a class that has Misty Step on its list -- so Sorcerer, Wizard, and Warlock, but not Cleric or Bard.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I actually typed out and submitted an answer for "No" and then deleted and rewrote this one because I convinced myself otherwise in the process.

I'm assuming "knowing" the spell isn't enough to qualify it to go on any class list right?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose The class lists are what they are, the only way anything gets added to a class list is if you have a feat or ability that specifically say it does (such as domain spells or warlock's expanded spell list).  And if you wanted to cast Misty Step using slots, you do have to prepare it (if you have to do that).  I mean, you know the spell, but it doesn't say it's always prepared.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was almost of the opinion that RAW the spell is castable by spontaneous casters (because they only need to know the spell to cast it) but  *not* by prepared casters (because preparing and knowing are different, and they prepare spells from their spellbook rather than from memory) 
But according to the wizard's description, the spellbook is the "repository of spells that you know" so I believe that the spell would actually be added to the spellbook as well, without the gold and time investment that usually accompanies adding a new spell to it.

Comment: It may be worth updating the answer given the [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), which updated each class's Spellcasting (or Pact Magic) feature to say you can only use that class's slots to cast spells of that class (e.g. "cleric spells" for cleric), in accordance with what the Sage Advice Compendium says about Magic Initiate.

Answer (score 4):

### Classes that prepare spells cannot cast *misty step* using a spell slot unless they also prepare the spell separately

#### A spell must be prepared or known/learned to cast it using spell slots

The Wizard's [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#Spellcasting-410) feature states:

> [...] You prepare the list of wizard spells that are available for you to cast. To do so, choose a number of wizard spells from your spellbook equal to your Intelligence modifier + your wizard level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots. [...]

Various other classes use similar wording requiring that a spell be prepared if you want to cast it using spell slots. Thus, when a spell is merely learned, like with Fey Teleportation, it is not prepared and cannot be cast using spell slots.

> You **learn** the *misty step* spell and can cast it once without expending a spell slot. You regain the ability to cast it in this way when you finish a short or long rest.

Of course, you can prepare *misty step* **and** have the Fey Teleportation feat, in which case you can use your spell slots to cast *misty step*.

---

### Classes that know/learn spells can cast *misty step* if, and only if it is considered a class spell for them

#### Spell slots can only be used to cast spells that are associated with (one of) your class(es)

The *Player's Handbook* has received [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) changing the wordings of every Spellcasting and Pact Magic feature. For instance, the sorcerer's Spellcasting feature said, pre-errata:

> The sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your spells of 1st level and higher.

Post-errata, it now reads:

> The sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your **sorcerer** spells of 1st level and higher.

Thus, the spell slots provided by a class can only be used to cast spells from/of that class. They cannot be used to cast spells that are not considered their own class spells.

---

#### How do you know if a spell is associated with (one of) your class(es)?

The following three Q&As (one is closed as a duplicate) have differing answers to this question:

- [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182)
- [Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954)
- [If I am a Celestial Warlock and I take the Magic Initiate - Cleric (Cure Wounds), does that now count as a Warlock spell for me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157765)

It seems inconclusive then, and a GM will have to make a ruling whether or not *misty step* (which appears on the sorcerer spell list) counts as a sorcerer spell for you when it is obtained through the Fey Teleportation feat.

If it does count as one, you can use your spell slots on it. If it does not count as one, you cannot use your spell slots on it.

Comment: Does this change with the wording of the *Fey Touched* feat as opposed to *Fey Teleporation*?

Comment: @esh [My own answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/177810) to a related question probably answers that