# If I am a Celestial Warlock and I take the Magic Initiate - Cleric (Cure Wounds), does that now count as a Warlock spell for me?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock

If I am a Celestial Warlock and I take the Magic Initiate - Cleric (Cure Wounds), does that now count as a Warlock spell for me?

Since under The Celestial it says: "The following spells are added to the warlock spell list for you." and Cure Wounds is on the list.

This last part in the SAC would lead me to believe yes: "In short, you must follow your character’s normal
spellcasting rules, which determine whether you can
expend spell slots on the 1st-level spell you learn from
Magic Initiate."

Bonus question, option 2: If i took the feat after having one level in Celestial Warlock, could I take Cure Wounds using Magic Initiate - Warlock.

Comment: Related: [Are spells learned from Feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/are-spells-learned-from-feats-considered-to-be-associated-with-your-class/110955#110955) and [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell)

Comment: I'd call it a dupe, from the "that answer answers this question" perspective, but they're such different questions.

Comment: @ben Yeah. I had the same thought, which is why I only posted them the links as related. I figured I'd leave it up to others to help decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/106192/55869), a spell is considered a Class Spell if it's listed in the class' spell list. So given that the Celestial patron adds it to the Warlock Spell List I would say that it does count as a warlock spell and can be cast as such.

Worth noting though is that after testing this with the DDB Character Sheet it doesn't seem to be treated as such. You get the single use from the feat and that's it.

As a DM however I would rule that it does count as a  Warlock spell and can be cast using a pact slot as if you had learned it normally.