# Is it possible for a single-class Eldritch Knight to learn Hex, or Hunter's Mark, etc?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, fighter, eldritch-knight

I am trying to build a **singly-classed** Fighter with ready access to a bonus damage on hit spell like Hex or Hunter's Mark, but I'm not seeing many options for that combination.

While Eldritch Knight gives access to Wizard spells, Wizards don't have access to either Hex or Hunter's Mark. Nor does Magic Initiate (which would be easy to pick up with the Fighter's ASI progression) allow a purloined Hex to be cast with Eldritch Knight spell slots — at least per my reading of the feat and [this answer here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68481), it's once per long rest regardless of whether or not you have spell slots.

Is there some other way for an Eldritch Knight to learn some sort of damage boosting concentration spell along with their other spells?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! With the new Tasha's Cauldron of Everything feats, you can pick [Fey Touched](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/fey-touched), allowing you to select Hunters Mark *or* Hex as a learned spell

Answer (score 14):

There is a spell like that on the wizard list, *bestow curse*, with which you can choose the option that:

> While the target is cursed, your attacks and spells deal an extra ld8
>   necrotic damage to the target. (PHB 218)

However, it is a 3rd level necromancy spell, so you have to be 14th level to learn it. Also it takes an action to cast, is touch range and there is a save against it. Compared to *hex*/*hunter's mark* or other 3rd level spells, it might be a little weak, even if at that point you attack 3 times in a turn.

Answer (score 14):

**Yes**. This is now possible thanks to the addition of *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. You can select the [Fey Touched](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/fey-touched) feat in order to learn a "1st-level spell... from the divination or enchantment school of magic."

Since [Hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex) is an enchantment spell and [Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) is a divination spell and both are first level, you may pick either one.

This feat also grants +1 to Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma as well as learning [Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step). Both spells may be cast once per day using this feat as well as with spell slots if you have them.

---

Everything below here is the old answer, which used to be correct but is now obsolete and wrong.

> **No**, there does not appear to be a way for Eldritch Knights to learn cross-class spells that work with their slots.
>
> This answer used to suggest it was allowed based on a strict reading of the grammar used in the Eldritch Knight subclass writeup.  This seemed possible due to text which allowed you to use slots to cast spells that you knew.  However, PHB errata has since rewritten that text so that it explicitly states that you may use slots to cast wizard spells that you know.
>
> Since these spells are not wizard spells you may not use your spell slots to cast them.  You only gain the ability to cast warlock spells with the warlock spellcasting feature and the same thing for ranger spells.  Therefore, without multiclassing, these spells are inaccessible to you to cast with spell slots.
>
> ---
>
> It's not quite the same as hex and hunter's mark, but you might look into **Shadow Blade** (*XGtE p. 164*).  It's a 2nd-level illusion spell that you can learn at level 8 with your unrestricted wizard spell choice.  It creates a powerful blade dealing 2d8 psychic + str/dex on every hit.  It only lasts for a minute and if your concentration is broken, you just lost your weapon.  However, it has finesse, light, and thrown properties (reform as a bonus action).

Answer (score 3):

#### Be a denizen of Theros and worship Nylea.

If you find yourself in a Theros campaign and elect to become a champion of [Nylea](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#NyleasChampions), at 3+ piety score you gain the following blessing:

> As a devotee of Nylea, you have proven yourself a guardian of the wilds. **You can cast *hunter’s mark* with this trait a number of times equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of once)**. You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest. Wisdom is your spellcasting ability for this spell.

Comment: The question specifies using Eldritch Knight spell slots for it; Wis times per long rest isn’t that.

Comment: No it doesn’t. Not using spell slots is the reason magic initiate is inferior. Sufficiently high wisdom makes this option equivalent or even better than having to use spell slots.