# If a cleric has the Gift of the Metallic Dragon feat, can they cast the Cure Wounds spell without preparing it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, spellcasting, cleric

The description of the [Gift of the Metallic Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/gift-of-the-metallic-dragon) feat provided in the *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* sourcebook states, in part (my emphasis):

> **Draconic Healing.** You learn the *cure wounds* spell. You can cast this spell without expending a spell slot. Once you cast this spell in this way, you can’t do so again until you finish a long rest. **You can also cast this spell using spell slots you have.** [...]

As a Cleric with this feat, does the last sentence mean I don't need to prepare *cure wounds* for my spell list, effectively granting me an additional prepared spell?

Comment: Related: compare Magic Initiate, which is missing that highlighted wording.  Then the situation apparently depends on the details of how classes can have to prepare spells or can cast any they "know" permanently.  [Can you cast a spell learned from the Magic Initiate feat using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68451)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### A cleric with this feat can cast *cure wounds* using spell slots without preparing it.

You have made the correct observation. The text of the feat is unambiguous:

> You can also cast this spell using spell slots you have.

The feat creates an exception for the cleric. Normally, a cleric must prepare spells to be able to cast them. However, the *specific beats general* rule tells us:

> Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

The feat provides a specific rule: it permits us to cast *cure wounds* using our spells slots. Since it does not say we must prepare the spell, we need not prepare the spell.

Comment: MFW I'm a Life Cleric so I've always got Cure Wounds prepared anyway. Well thanks for the input!

Comment: Yeah, it's not a fantastic gift for a cleric -- doing what you were gonna do anyway, but slightly more efficiently.  It's probably a *better* gift for a sorcerer/wizard/warlock, who normally has no access to healing at all.